# Django-registration and activation failure

Tags: django, django-registration

I don't under stand how django-registration is handling activation failure? Say, a user just uses a dummy activation key and invokes the url in browser /activation/"key". Now, activation will fail but which url should users be directed to? And, also, the user should be shown the error message. Correct? But, I find after clicking activate, user is shown the activate.html only.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the docstring for the function `activate`:

> On unsuccessful activation, will render the template
>   `registration/activate.html` to display an error message; to
>   override thise, pass the argument `template_name` (see below).

The default url captured:

```
              url(r'^activate/(?P<activation_key>\w+)/$',
                   activate,
                   {'backend': 'registration.backends.default.DefaultBackend'},
                   name='registration_activate'),
```

On success, the `activate` view redirects to a success URL, therefore the only purpose of the `activate.html` template is on failure.

**Update:** looking at the instructions, it even says this explicitly in the "templates required" section:

> **registration/activate.html**
>
> Used if account activation fails. With
>   the default setup, has the following
>   context:
>
> `activation_key`
>       The activation key used during the activation attempt.

Answer (score 0):

I think django-registration does not handle this properly. Perhaps it is a good idea to file a bug with the upstream code.

Had a to write some template code here as a work around. 
https://github.com/arky/pootle/commit/8e7f771499206cb6c636a80bc8156db1ecd722b1